# Replace duplicate values with Null and keep only last value

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
   ID      Date       EoM_Val    Val
---------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-30    3946750     3
  AAA   2021-06-30    3946750     2
  BBB   2021-06-30    2792182     6
  BBB   2021-06-30    2792182     7
```

And basically, I want to only keep the the last `EoM_Val` based on the `ID` and `Date` columns, such that the final output looks like this:

```
   ID      Date       EoM_Val    Val
---------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-30                3
  AAA   2021-06-30    3946750     2
  BBB   2021-06-30                6
  BBB   2021-06-30    2792182     7
```

Is there a good way of doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this code, I hope It may use

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"ID":["AAA","AAA","BBB","BBB"],"Date":["2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-06-30"],"EoM_Val":[3946750,3946750,2792182,2792182],"Val":[3,2,6,7]})
df2=df.drop_duplicates(["EoM_Val"],keep="first")
indices = list(df2.index)
df.loc[indices,'EoM_Val'] = ""
print(df)
```

I got output like this

```
   ID      Date       EoM_Val    Val
---------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-30                3
  AAA   2021-06-30    3946750     2
  BBB   2021-06-30                6
  BBB   2021-06-30    2792182     7
```

Comment: This doesn't work `ID`-wise if the `EoM_Val`s are identical for 2 consecutive `ID`-groups.